# I get err 500 when modifing template on django

Tags: python, django, templates

I've a deployed Django project [link here](https://sadraedu.com), every time i try to mod the template server give `500 error` while it doesn't have any bugs.

some times the error vanishes by itself and some times i should reset the template to the previous version.

my `back` is written with `python-Django` and `front` is written with `jquery, bootstrap, django-template`.

there is probability that the site has problem with the below code:

```
#signup/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import signup_form

def Signup(request):
    form = signup_form(request.POST or None)
    context={
        'form':form,
        'authed':False,
        'name':"",
        'gender':"",
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        context['authed']   = True
        context['name']     = request.POST['student_name']
        context['gender']   = request.POST['gender']
        form.save()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)
```

Comment: And how are you running your server? And which server do you run?

Comment: I've bought a python server (one year plan). and i run it by creating a new python app in cpanel

Comment: And you don't know which software it runs as a web server (Apache, nginx, ...)? I presume that the issue is with restarting web server, but it is a very wild guess

Comment: it runs apache and I've restarted many times?

Comment: And you get something in the apache logs?

Comment: nothings wrong in logs.

Comment: can it be the server providers fault?

Comment: To be honest we run everything on our servers, we just don't trust anyone, so it is difficult to say. I don't like those pre-provisioned servers, not comfortable with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks of all, the problem was solved.
it was not my app or my own fault I submited a ticket to the server support describing the problem and they answered it was `server providers fault` and now i get always 200 in my site.
again thanks of all for paying attention.